# Android Layout extend on element until another

Tags: android, layout, position

I'm trying to position an imageview to the right and extend the editor text until this image.

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Insert the possibile option"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:lines="2"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/insert"
        android:layout_gravity="right"

    />
```

but the EditText ends to "Insert the possibile option" because I'm using wrap_content, but if I try with match_parent or fill, I don't see the ImageView

How can I organize my Layout?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `android:weight="1"` to `EditText`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Insert the possibile option"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:lines="2"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/insert"
        android:layout_gravity="right"

    />
```